# Concat/Append to the end of a specific line of text file in Python

Tags: python

I need to add some text to the end of a specific line in a text file. I'm currently trying to use a method similar to this:

```
entryList = [5,4,3,8]
dataFile = open("file.txt","a+)
for i in dataFile:
     for j in entryList:
     lines[i] = lines[i].strip()+entryList[j]+" "
dataFile.write(lines[i])
```

I'd like to add the numbers immediately following the text.

Text file setup:

```
it is 
earlier it was 
before that it was 
later it will be
```

Comment: Close quotes on second line and fix indentation on fifth line.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out what you are trying to do.  What is your desired output based on the the input in "Text file setup"?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned specific line in the question and in your code you are writing for every line.

`import fileinput`

`entryList = [5,4,3,8]`

`count = 0`

`for line in fileinput.FileInput('data.txt',inplace=1):
    print line+str(entryList[count])+" "
    count+=1`

Answer (score 0):

Reading from and then writing to the same file is not such a good idea. I suggest opening it as needed:

```
entryList = [5,4,3,8]

with open("file.txt", "r") as dataFile:
  # You may want to add '\n' at the end of the format string
  lines = ["{} {} ".format(s.strip(), i) for s,i in zip(dataFile, entryList)]

with open("file.txt", "w") as outFile:
  outFile.writelines(lines)
```